# Trouble calling a base class and passing in the correct base constructor parameters

Tags: c#, parameters, constructor

I'm using an online teach-yourself-c# website testing my knowledge of inhereitence and this exercise I cant seem to resolve:

question:

> 1. Create a constructor on the base type Atom that accepts an integer named protons and an integer electrons. The constructor should set the values to the associated properties Protons and Electrons.
> 2. Implement a derived type Hydrogen that inherits from Atom and provides the correct arguments for protons and electrons to the base constructor.

Here is the code the exercise starts you with:

```
public class Atom
{
    public int Protons { get; set; }

    public int Electrons { get; set; }
}

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {

    }
}
```

Here is my solution code, it gets no compiler errors but the website is telling me it doesnt resolve question #2:

```
public class Atom
{
    public Atom ( int protons, int electrons)
    {
        Protons = protons;
        Electrons = electrons;
    }

    public int Protons { get; set; }
    public int Electrons { get; set; }

}

public class Hydrogen : Atom
{
    public Hydrogen() : base(1,1) { }

}

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Hydrogen hydrogen = new Hydrogen();
    }
}
```

The code compiles fine, but the website states that I have not completed the exercise as follows:

> Not all requirements have been met.
>
> You must call the base class, passing in the correct number of protons and
>       electrons.

Comment: It all looks fine to me. No one here can tell you why the website isn't happy with your code. All we can offer is opinions and guesses. You would have to ask the website author themselves.

Comment: Is website happy when you define ctor as `public Hydrogen(int protons, int electrons) : base(protons, electrons) { }` and create object as `new Hydrogen(1, 1);` ?

Comment: I tried that too (so proud i thought of it since you professionals did too =) ).  It compiles but the website says i have to use a parameterless constructor.  However, it is functional code for practical purposes.

Answer (score 1):

Their code parser is buggy. Just add a space between the base contractor parameters.

Use base(1, 1) instead of base(1,1). It will fix the error.

Comment: That worked!  How on earth did you know that?!!

Comment: As the code was ok, I tried several things in that website. That one worked  .